# Replace characters in go serialization by using custom MarshalJSON method

Tags: json, go, serialization, character-encoding

As far as I saw, I just did a customized `MarshalJSON` method in order to replace these characters:`\u003c` and `\u003e`: https://go.dev/play/p/xJ-qcMN9QXl

In the example above, i marshaled the similar struct by sending to marshal from an aux struct that contains the same fields and last step is to replace the fields that I actually need and the return.
As you can see in the print placed before returning from `MarshalJSON` method, the special characters were replaced, but after calling the `json.Marshal` func, the special characters remains the same.

Something I'm missing here but cannot figure it out. Appreciate your help.
Thankies :)

Comment: Use [`json.Encoder.SetEscapeHTML`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18.3#Encoder.SetEscapeHTML). Example: https://go.dev/play/p/1f4YW42ocSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Marshal` documentation of the json package https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal you will find the following paragraph:

> String values encode as JSON strings coerced to valid UTF-8, replacing invalid bytes with the Unicode replacement rune. So that the JSON will be safe to embed inside HTML  tags, the string is encoded using HTMLEscape, which replaces "<", ">", "&", U+2028, and U+2029 are escaped to "\u003c","\u003e", "\u0026", "\u2028", and "\u2029". This replacement can be disabled when using an Encoder, by calling SetEscapeHTML(false).

So try it using a `Encoder`, example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Name    string
    Surname string
    Likes   map[string]interface{}
    Hates   map[string]interface{}
    newGuy  bool //rpcclonable
}

func main() {
    foo := &Foo{
        Name:    "George",
        Surname: "Denkin",
        Likes: map[string]interface{}{
            "Sports":  "volleyball",
            "Message": "<Geroge> play volleyball <usually>",
        },
    }
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{} // or &strings.Builder{} as from the example of @mkopriva
    enc := json.NewEncoder(buf)
    enc.SetEscapeHTML(false)
    err := enc.Encode(foo)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I saw some comments using encoder before, but I thought that it wasn't really necesarry :) have a good day